# an html tag for displaying html received from a specific url

Tags: html, design-patterns

I created an API of sorts, that when you navigate to it, returns information in html.

On my website, I would like to have the web page reach out to the API and display the information as part of the web page (sort of like a webpage reaches out for an img). What HTML tag would be best suited to achieving this result? I came across the  and  tags but not really sure which would be best.

I am building this myself thus have full control over how the content is delivered back to the page. Is there specific pattern that is used for such "modular" sourcing of information? I could rewrite my website to - prior to serving the web page - reach out to the api and pull the info itself and then include the results in html but a) this would be more complex and require changes in several places b) will become really complex as the number of such api call results I would want to include increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) for this purpose and when you recieve html which you want to display , you can simply set html content in that iframe's ID :

```
document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document.write("<html><body>Here is your html</body></html>");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know, using iframes is rather depricated. I always use div-tags for such tasks.

`document.getElementById("targetdiv").innerHTML = "New HTML-Content";`
More info on divs: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp

Comment: Where is it written iFrames are deprecated , JS Fiddle uses iframes, Facebook uses it, and Div tags are never used for this purpose!

Comment: Ok, "deprecated" might be the wrong term. I'd rephrase it as: It's less en vogue these days, since usually you won't include a whole document, but query an API through AJAX for specific data, handle it somehow, and display it in some container. Which would be a div.

Comment: His response is html and that is why iframes are used for.

Comment: He further noted, that he has full control on how the information is delivered. Hence, he can change it from the html+head+body stuff to just a little `<span>Hello</span>`, which would save quite some data. And since there was a second question for a "designpattern" for displaying modular information, the ajax-div approach seems as a valid solution.